# How to Increase the defaault size of PE(physical extent) in LVM(logical volume manager)

Tags: linux, centos, lvm

I have created a LV of 16GB for testing purpose and it has a default PE size of 4mb, I want to increase the default size.How is it possible? What is the command for that.

Also, if there is a way to define the size while creating a LV, then also please help me.

I'm using CentOS 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size is set with the `-s` option when you `vgcreate` the volume group, but there is no reason to change it; it will not effect performance.

Comment: I don't consider the performance factor yet. As I mentioned, it was just for the training purpose. And as you mentioned that while creating volume-group , i can specify the size. But what if I want to change the default size after creating logical volume? Could you please answer that

Comment: @Abhinav, `vgchange` can change it, but only to a higher multiple of the original.

Comment: I got it. Tried and working successfully. Thanks